# Symfony4 service container circular dependency

Tags: circular-dependency, symfony4

In the process of migrating a symfony3.4 project to Symfony4 with *symfony-flex* …

After adapting the directory structure and proceeding to few adjustments, I now face what looks like a **circular dependency** error that comes to light during the application service container bootstrapping phase. Hitting the application (whether from the console or the fronted) raises some exception related to *Xdebug* saying *«nested function calls limit reached ('256')»*.

Looking at the backtrace reveals kind of a pattern that repeats itself and leads to the conclusion that *Xdebug* is not the one to blame but **two services depending indirectly on each-other** instead.

Involved services are:

- **Log manager** is a public service which helps persisting user actions to database:

  ```
  log_manager:
      class: Service\Log\LogManager
      public: true
      arguments:
          - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
          - "@?security.token_storage"
  ```
- **LoggableSubscriber** consumes *LogManager* service to create a new record when some application objects state change:

  ```
  Doctrine\Behavior\ORM\Loggable\LoggableSubscriber:
      public: false
      arguments:
          - "@log_manager"
          - "@event_dispatcher"
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
  ```

**Backtrace** *(please read from bottom to top)*:

```
==== ↑↑ PATTERN REPEATS ON AND ON ↑↑ ====
==== ONCE AGAIN DOCTRINE LOOKS FOR SUBSCRIBERS ====
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLoggableSubscriberService.php')
    in getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php (line 34)
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php')
    in getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php (line 74)
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)
==== "LOGMANAGER" NATURALLY REQUIRES DOCTRINE ENTITY MANAGER SERVICE ====
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php')
    in getLogManagerService.php (line 10)
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLogManagerService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLogManagerService.php')
    in getLoggableSubscriberService.php (line 11)

==== BUT OUR "LOGGABLESUBSCRIBER" IN TURN NEEDS THE "LOGMANAGER" SERVICE ====
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLoggableSubscriberService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)

==== DOCTRINE LOADS SUBSCRIBERS (ATTACHED VIA "TAG" PROPERTY) ====
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLoggableSubscriberService.php')
    in getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php (line 34)
==== ↑↑ PATTERN STARTS HERE ↑↑ ====

at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Dbal_ApiacmeConnectionService.php')
    in getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php (line 74)
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)

==== FIRST, OUR "LOGMANAGER" SERVICE DEPENDS ON DOCTRINE MAIN ENTITYMANAGER ====
at boDevDebugProjectContainer->load('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getDoctrine_Orm_ApiacmeEntityManagerService.php')
    in getLogManagerService.php (line 10)
at require('…/var/cache/bo/dev/ContainerTv5AUyL/getLogManagerService.php')
    in boDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 446)
↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑
…
```

**Is this purely a misconception issue ? Or is there a way to make the service container aware of this situation by setting some property/flag somewhere in the configuration so that it doesn't go mad ?** I saw several questions related to this topic but answers are specific to their question's context.

I was about to break the *LogManager* service dependency on doctrine's entity manager, making *LogManager* class unable to persist its underlying entity object to database by itself anymore and as a consequence delegating that job to the calling context by returning the instance to be persisted instead. I am not convinced this is the ideal solution though.

Suggested approach would really be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing *dependency injection* argument with a method call did fix the issue. My `log_manager` service definition now looks like this:

```
log_manager:
    class: Service\Log\LogManager
    public: true
    arguments:
        - "@?security.token_storage"
    calls:
        - ['setEntityManager', ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
```

Please comment/answer if there is a better way to solve the issue.